# Close modal when clicking outside - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, click

I want a modal to close when I click outside. In the code below, you can find the handleCloseClick function and also the render method.

How can I do this in React?

```
  handleCloseClick = (e) => {
    const { hideModal } = this.props

    e.preventDefault()   
    hideModal()
  }
```

The component I'm trying to pass props to close is CustomModal.

```
  render() {
    const { connectDropTarget } = this.props

    return (
      <CustomModal
        alternateModalClass='c-group-stickies-modal'
        onClosePress={this.handleCloseClick}
        alternateCloseButtonClass='c-group-stickies-modal__close-button'
      >
        {this.renderModalHeading()}

        <CustomModal.Content
          alternateContentClass='c-group-stickies-modal__content'
        >
          {connectDropTarget(
            <div className='c-group-stickies-modal__stickies'>
              <Masonry
                className={'my-gallery-class'}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
              >
                {this.renderGroupStickies()}
              </Masonry>
            </div>
          )}
        </CustomModal.Content>
      </CustomModal>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Is the custom modal component something you wrote, or from another library?

Comment: There are a few really nice clickoutside event handler packages for React, I use [react-onclickoutside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside).

Comment: @TPorter it's from a component someone else wrote :)